# c# DbSet - Internal object cannot be got

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ado.net

I need to switch an entity to internal. So I create it. No build/runtime error. But when I want to use the DbSet object I can't because the object seems not initialized !

My ContextEntities:

```
public partial class Entities
{
   internal DbSet<Employee> EmployeeSet { get; set; }
}
```

I use like this:

```
Entities context = new Entities();
List<Employee> employees = context.EmployeeSet.ToList();
```

But "EmployeeSet" is null. I think it's because it is not instantiated in get. It works if I use public like this:

```
public partial class Entities
{
   public DbSet<Employee> EmployeeSet { get; set; }
}
```

Questions:
Can it work if a DbSet is marked internal? If so how? Why does that break it?
(thanks Scott Stafford)

Comment: I assume the question is: can it work if a DbSet is marked internal?  If so how?  Why does that break it?  I imagine the answer is that the "convention" requires them to be public and doesn't wire in the proper code otherwise...

Comment: Yes sorry! :) The question is: can it work if a DbSet is marked internal? If so how? thanks Scott.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It will not be automatically instantiated if it is not set to `public`. You can manually instantiate it using [`Set<TEntity>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696521%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) method.

```
public partial class Entities
{
   internal DbSet<Employee> EmployeeSet { get; set; }

   public Entities()
   {
       EmployeeSet = Set<Employee>();
   }
}
```

Comment: could you help me for the same problem on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646182/c-dbset-internal-object-association-cannot-be-got ?

Comment: Thank you so much for Set<TEntity>! I was looking everywhere for a way to initialise a DbSet.

Comment: 4 years later...but thanks for this!  I recently set all my EF entities to internal (creating a class lib with only one exposed class for an API) and ran into this.  Since I already have a partial setup for the DbContext (to allow me to dynamically set the connection string), it was the perfect place to also add these lines of code to Set<> each DbSet.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem and was able to fix it by only setting the getter as `internal`.

```
public partial class Entities
{
   public DbSet<Employee> EmployeeSet { internal get; set; }
}
```

Comment: While the other is still preferable (internal get with public setter?), this actually works so have my vote. This alternative can be useful to whoever may not be in the situation for using the accepted answer.