# c# DbSet - Internal object association cannot be got

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ado.net

I have the same problem of
[this topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636734/c-dbset-internal-object-cannot-be-got) but on the association between entities.

```
internal virtual ICollection<Adress> Adresses { get; set; }
```

It works if I use like this:

```
public virtual ICollection<Adress> Adresses { get; set; }
```

How can I initialize Adresses ?

Comment: What is a difference between those two lines of code?

Comment: Sorry I forgot changes (copy-paste ! :P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework will only work with `public` properties. If you want to use different access modifies you should check out nHibernate.

Comment: oh! it's bad news! nHibernate is a very long to introduce in a project.

Comment: @Sam If you keep the `internal` modifier you won't be able to unit test also.

Comment: You've right. But in my case, I really need to have this object in internal because the end-user don't need this access.

Comment: @Sam Consider passing DTOs to the end users

Comment: Apparently, it is possible to use internal access modifiers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636734/c-sharp-dbset-internal-object-cannot-be-got