# Internal access for entities in Entity Framework makes simple linq where query crash

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, internalsvisibleto

I am developing a library which use EF for database access. To avoid expose the entities outside the library, I have set the access of all tables to internal (I have also set to internal the Entity Container Access). The problem is that now, inside the library, when I try to get an entity by its id, the `Where` query throws an exception, I do not why.

The internal access has been set in the diagram (.edmx file), and in a static class that I am using as a factory inside the library I have something like this:

```
var id = 1234;
var mec = new MyEntitiesContainer();
var myEntity = mec.MyEntities.Where(e => e.MyEntitiesId == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Simple where query to get a concrete entity (row) from the database by its id.

When all entities class access are public, there is no problem, but when I have set them to internal this exception is thrown:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: source     
    at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this behaviour?  I only ask because I am experiencing the same problem?

Answer (score 5):

**Update!** Actually found a more direct working solution to this problem:

1. Open the edmx in the designer
2. Set "Entity Container Access" to Internal
3. Be sure all Entities have "Access" set to Public
4. Expand the edmx and edit the entity t4 (NOT the *.Context.tt)
5. In the t4 search for `Accessibility.ForType(entity)` and replace it with `"Internal"` (or `"Friend"` for VB)
6. Save/Re-run the T4 and that's it.

After following those steps no part of your EF items should be visible outside the Assembly and everything should "just work".

If you still experience the "Value cannot be null" exception see the "gotcha" at the bottom of this post.

---

This is already answered here: [c# DbSet - Internal object cannot be got](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7636734/c-sharp-dbset-internal-object-cannot-be-got)

The gist is that if you set an entityset/dbset property as internal it will not be automatically instantiated by EF. But you can manually instantiate it as described in the accepted answer on that page.

---

Another gotcha to look out for:

There is a bug in VS2012 (version 11.0.60610.01 Update 3 is my current environment) where the designer won't properly set items back to Public in the underlying edmx file even though it reports as though it does.

So even after setting items back to public, re-running the context t4 and rebuilding you'll still receive that exception.

The only workaround I've found is to open the edmx file and edit it manually, setting the internals back to public.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the bug in VS2012, where the EF designer doesn't properly set items back to public. I hit this exact bug, and couldn't figure out how to get EF to set my Entity Sets on my Container to Public. So I followed your advice and just edited the EDMX, and now everythings works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How is code from another namespace meant to set the properties in objects from your namespaces? If you think about how EF lives in a different namespace to your code yet populates properties in it, I'd venture that `public` is somewhat necessary.

Comment: All classes in the library are under the same namespace: the partial classes for the entities and the factory class which does the where query. I think that if it is a problem, a compile-time error should be raised, but I have said, all classes are under the same namespace.
Thank you!

Comment: Namespaces have nothing to do with internal classes and their visibility. Assemblies is what is important, that is the project and the resulting dll. Internal classes are only visible in that assembly, but they are visible to all other classes in that assemly, no matter what the other classes namespaces are.